# Tree with multiple-level hierarchy in WD?

Tags: treeview, abap, alv, webdynpro

[This](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/c060fcb4-2c62-2b10-d2b2-f32407a5cc6f?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&32461362849084) tutorial for "creating an ALV tree" describes a 2-level hierarchy which is more like grouping than a tree. Is there a way to create a tree control with a variable depth and width?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of levels by creating correspondent number of columns as you want, like it given in those manual:

```
DATA: lr_column TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_WD_COLUMN.

lr_column = lr_value->IF_SALV_WD_COLUMN_SETTINGS~GET_COLUMN( 'CARRID' ).
lr_column->IF_SALV_WD_COLUMN_HIERARCHY~SET_HIERARCHY_COLUMN( abap_true ).
...
lr_columnN =  
lr_columnN->IF_SALV_WD_COLUMN_HIERARCHY~SET_HIERARCHY_COLUMN( abap_true ).
```

All they should have hierarchy property (`SET_HIERARCHY_COLUMN(  )`) and the last one could be set as final (a leaf) by setting such property

```
lr_columnN->IF_SALV_WD_COLUMN_HIERARCHY~SET_LAST_HIER_COLUMN_AS_LEAF( abap_true ).
```

So you specify levels of your ALV hieararchy table yourself **by applying correspondent property** to target columns. ALV engine will render the hierarchy himself.